# Azure Data Factory - Initial Load SQL Server then CDC

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl

I have a task where I need to load 2 years of data from a table to Data lake using ADF and then continue using CDC.

I am new to ADF and was wondering how to achieve this since CDC on the table is yet to be activated. My question would be how to move from initial load further with CDC without missing data or ingesting all table.

Also with CI/CD how would the pipeline work for stg env in terms of being scheduled or not? Only working with subset of data for testing purpose etc?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will break your question in 3 parts :

**1st part :** loading the 2 years of data requires an ADF pipeline that uses a Copy Activity to move data. You need just to configure your source dataset to point to your table and your sink dataset to your Data Lake storage.
Since you mentioned that you have a large dataset, consider optimizing the copy activity by using data integration units (DIU) for parallel processing and staging if necessary to speed up the transfer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-data-tool?tabs=data-factory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance

**2nd part:** CDC After Initial Load

If CDC is not already enabled on your source database, you will need to enable it and it depends on your database type.

You can also create another ADF pipeline that uses the CDC feature with a combination of change tracking features of your source database

For SQL databases, ADF provides a built-in CDC feature for some sources or you can manually implement it using watermarks (a column with a sequential identifier like a timestamp or an auto-incrementing primary key).

To make sure that you don't miss any data between the initial load and the start of the CDC, you might need to:

- Overlap the initial load and CDC timeframe slightl
- Use a high-watermark from the initial load to ensure CDC picks up exactly where the initial load left off

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-change-data-capture

**CI/CD and triggers :**

For CI/CD in, you can manage your code in a source control system (like Azure Repos, GitHub) and automate deployments using Azure DevOps or GitHub Actions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery

When it comes to development to staging to production, you can use ARM templates for resource deployment across environments with the parameters in your templates to handle environment-specific settings such as connections strings or file paths.

You can use the trigger to schedule pipeline runs and if you are looking continuous processing consider using tumbling window triggers for continuous processing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance! When we mention staging copy which seems to me something I should use, my end goal is ADLS2 so I do not need it as interim between something else? Also when you say overlap, you mean to have two pipelines extract data at the same time? One pipeline for 2 years of data and the second one to pull data from CDC table?

Comment: Also when it comes to CI/CD I am wondering if I have stg ADF does pipeline in is also scheduled all the time to pull data or? I am a bit confused how staging would work. Prod would be active all the time but dev and stage are a bit confusing to me.

Comment: For complex transformations copying data to a staging area (temporary storage in ADLS2) can help you improve performance. Sometimes, the raw data isn't in a format suitable for direct analysis or processing. Staging areas allow for an intermediate step where data can be cleaned, reformatted before moving to the final storage for consumption.

Comment: For overlapping, a common approach is to have one pipeline that initially loads a large volume of historical data (like in your case 2 years of data) into your storage. Concurrently or subsequently, another pipeline is designed to handle continuous, incremental updates (often from a Change Data Capture (CDC) ) to keep the dataset up to date with the latest changes.

Comment: WHat I wanted to say that for the pipelines one for bulk historical loads and another for ongoing incremental update. In this way, you ensure that your data storage contains a complete historical record up to the present moment.

Comment: Getting back to your concerns about CI/CD, if you want to use a staging area within ADLS Gen2 I assume it will be in this case : if your data requires pre-processing or cleansing before it reaches its final form in the data lake. If not, you might choose to load data directly into its final location in ADLS Gen2, bypassing a separate staging step.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for the help! One more question I read about CDC and ADF and I could not figure out how it works. It says I do not need to state any IDs and timestamps. So it reads CDC tables and then remember what it has read? Just to clarify how it works in the background.